# How to init parent's member?

Tags: c++

```
class Parent

{
public:
    int member;

    Parent():
        member(0)
    {
    }
};

class Child:
    public Parent
{
public:
    Child():
        member(1)  //error
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Parent

{
public:
    int member;

    Parent(int m = 0):
        member(m)  // constructor takes an argument, default as 0
    {
    }
};

class Child:
    public Parent
{
public:
    Child():
        Parent(1)  // refer to super class's constructor here
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: you beat me to it :) Although in my version I don't change the base class's public interface

Comment: @Armen Yours is pretty good too. I don't think I sinned though since the class's user doesn't have to change his code. It's a developer's choice either way.

Comment: In both answers the constructor taking an int as argument should be marked `explicit`, more so in this one where the constructor is public.

Answer (score 6):

```
class Parent{
private:
    int member;
public:
    Parent():
        member(0){
    }
protected:

    explicit Parent(int x):
        member(x){
    }
};

class Child:
    public Parent {
public:
    Child():
        Parent(1){
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 This is a good answer if you want Parent objects to ONLY have a member value of 0, but want derived objects to be able to set member accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to:

```
class Child:
    public Parent
{
public:
    Child()
    {
      member = 1;
    }
};
```

or try:

```
class Child:
    public Parent
{
public:
    Child():Parent(),member(1)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `member = 1;` in the function body.

Explanation: The initialization list is only for a class' own fields (including constructors of parent classes). Besides that, the parent class will be constructed first (and thus its initialization list has already been executed when your child class is beind constructed) so your code would construct *member* again which makes no sense.

(Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/29860/)

Answer (score 0):

The initializer list is there to allow to use some other constructor than the default one.  Obviously, a Child constructor can't choose anything else than the Parent constructor to use.  So two solutions:

- add a constructor to Parent doing what you want, make it protected if needed
- simply add an assignment in Child constructor.